# Is there a similar server side IDE for Python (like Spyder) similar to running R-studio server?

Tags: python, r, rstudio, spyder

I am currently running r-studio via my server at work which is amazing having all the cores at my disposal when running really intensive algos... not to mention I can code anywhere via a web browser.  My question is, is there something similar for say Spyder and developing in Python?  I code 50/50, R/Python and would love to set up a similar workflow.  Thoughts?

Comment: not sure what you mean but `ipython --notebook` may be what you are looking for

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `Rstudio-server`, unfortunately similar tool like that is not available. The closest to rstudio is `Ipython notebook`: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/notebook.html

Comment: Thanks I was afraid someone was going to say that! :)

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Once we embed the IPython notebook (in 2.4 I hope), it'll be possible to connect through it to kernels running in your server and use at the same time all our other plugins to do your development.